# How to use RoutingKey with ServiceStack and RabbitMQ

Tags: servicestack, rabbitmq

I have two identical sites which will consume RabbitMQ messages using the new [Rabbit MQ](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ) client. The producer ideally should be able to designate the site either by queue name or routing key. The former I can do as a Publish parameter but the latter I have no access to. Furthermore, on the service side, the consumer appears only able to subscribe to convention-based queue names, i.e. mq.myrequest.inq and I don't seem to be able to take advantage of the routing key.

Is there a way I can publish and subscribe using my own routing key, or register the handler based on an explicit queue name, i.e mq.myrequest.site1.inq ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't. ServiceStack's RabbitMq support is conventionally based on Type names and is opinionated to function as a work queue. It was designed to be config-free and simple to use so automatically takes care of the details of which exchanges, routing keys and queue names to use.

If you need advanced or custom configuration it's best to instead use the underlying [RabbitMQ.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client) directly.

Comment: For now I have used the static QueueNames.SetQueuePrefix("site1:") to get around the problem, but a suggestion would be to have some control over queue naming, perhaps by allowing sub-classing of QueueNames and maybe a QueueNames factory inserted into the queue server constructor? A user's implementation of QueueNames could allow access to the component parts of the queue name to allow combinations such as mq.sub.part.MyType.ext.inq which would avoid situations where the same request type is used in the same host.

Comment: @NeilDobson ok [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/1b86fa3df6b40fa85520090f69d48e7f05d32f46) should help.

Comment: This looks great. I forked the code with a view of doing this differently, but your solution is far more elegant. I'll take a look now.

Comment: Well it works fine, but i'm not sure about the implementation of the queue resolver fn. By default the queue name is constructed from: QueuePrefix + MqPrefix + typeName + queueSuffix. And you are free to access and change the prefix using the SetQueuePrefix static methods. However once you implement your own ResolveQueueNameFn the prefix is no longer used. But it wouldn't be clear why without studying the code.

Comment: An example: type of MyType would result in a queue name of pre:mq:MyType.inq but once you override queue name, the prefix and mq: is dropped. In order to re-instate the the same naming convention you need something like: QueueNames.ResolveQueueNameFn = (typeName, extension) => string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", QueueNames.QueuePrefix, QueueNames.MqPrefix, site, typeName, extension);

Comment: One could argue that the Getters should be implemented as: return QueuePrefix + MqPrefix + ResolveQueueNameFn(messageType.Name, ".inq"). Please advise if there is a better place to discuss this further?

Comment: Nah, the QueuePrefix is there if that's all you need, otherwise if you're going to provide a QueueName strategy it's best to have total control so that it can handle any format you want.

Comment: On reflection, its all good. I have access to all component parts in order to build any custom queue name, and its working nicely in a couple of apps.